# mPDF horizontal - PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, mpdf

Preciso gerar um PDF de relatório, com as seguintes especificações:

```
$this->load->helper('mpdf');
$html = $this->load->view('relatorio/interessados_relatorio_impressao', $data=NULL, true);
pdf_create($html, 'interessados_relatorio_' . date('dmyhis'), true);
```

Até aí, tudo bem, gera e faz o download. Porém, ele gera o PDF na vertical... E como é relatório, gostaria que fosse na horizontal.

Alguém pode me ajudar com esta questão?

Comment: Não dá pra ter ideia de como tá a declaração do `mpdf` com esse pouco trecho de código. Tenta ir na origem do `helper`, lá na pasta, acha o arquivo `mpdf.php` e procura por algo em torno de `new mPDF('utf-8','A4', [...]);`, se encontrar, adiciona um `L`, ficando assim `'A4-L'`.

Comment: Fiz isto, deu certo, podes postar sua resposta?